# how to add imageviews to gridpane using a forloop

Tags: loops, javafx, gridpane

here's my code.this prompts a exception saying "IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Grid hgap=5.0, vgap=5.0, alignment=TOP_LEFT"

File file = new File("D:\SERVER\Server Content\Apps\icons");

```
            File[] filelist1 = file.listFiles();
            ArrayList<File> filelist2 = new ArrayList<>();
            hb = new HBox();

            for (File file1 : filelist1) {
                filelist2.add(file1);

            }

            System.out.println(filelist2.size());

                for (int i = 0; i < filelist2.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(filelist2.get(i).getName());
                    image = new Image(filelist2.get(i).toURI().toString());

                    pic = new ImageView();
                    pic.setFitWidth(130);
                    pic.setFitHeight(130);

                    gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
                    gridpane.setHgap(5);
                    gridpane.setVgap(5);
                    pic.setImage(image);
                    hb.getChildren().add(pic);  

                }
```

Comment: What are you doing with gridpane before/afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding Items to a `GridPane` is a little different.

***[From the Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)***

> To use the GridPane, an application needs to set the layout
>   constraints on the children and add those children to the gridpane
>   instance. Constraints are set on the children using static setter
>   methods on the GridPane class
>
> Applications may also use convenience methods which combine the steps
>   of setting the constraints and adding the children

So in your example, you first need to decide : **How many images do I need in one row ?**

Lets say your answer is **4**, then your code becomes : (There are diff approaches to it, I am writing down the simplest one. You can use anything, loops for rows and colums being a good alternative ;)
)

```
//Can be set once, no need to keep them inside loop
gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
gridpane.setHgap(5);
gridpane.setVgap(5);

//Declaring variables for Row Count and Column Count
int imageCol = 0;
int imageRow = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < filelist2.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(filelist2.get(i).getName());
     image = new Image(filelist2.get(i).toURI().toString());

     pic = new ImageView();
     pic.setFitWidth(130);
     pic.setFitHeight(130);

     pic.setImage(image);
     hb.add(pic, imageCol, imageRow );
     imageCol++;

     // To check if all the 4 images of a row are completed
     if(imageCol > 3){
          // Reset Column
          imageCol=0;
          // Next Row
          imageRow++;
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm adding a list of images from a directory.When they are added,my Scrollpane gets crowded.How can I keep spacings between images?